# How to split an HTML table in half and display on one page when printing

Tags: html, css, printing

I have a table with several rows in my HTML. When the HTML is printed, the table is cut in half and extra rows are printed on the next page. Is there a way to split the table into two and display vertically next to each other on the same page?

Here is the HTML:

```css
#wrapTable {
  width: auto;
  border: 0px solid;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin:0">
  <table id="wrapTable">
    <tr>
      <th> Col1 </th>
      <th> Col2 </th>
      <th> Col3 </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Row1 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Row2 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Row3 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Row4 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Row5 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Row6 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Row7 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Row8 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Row9 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Row10 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table id="wrapTable">
    <tr>
      <td> Row11 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Row12 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Row13 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Row14 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Row15 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Row16 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Row17 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Row18 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Row19 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Row20 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I am trying to display all the rows in the same page by splitting the table into two and displaying them vertically next to each other.

Comment: Please supply the code you tried and a better explination as to what is happening. A jsfiddle.net will help as well. To answer your question, there probably is a way.

Comment: You can use a media query with CSS to display a table differently for printing than on a screen, but without providing your HTML, we won't be able to help you.

Comment: Thank you @freginold for editing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the desired result by using css property "display:inline".

```css
#wrapTable {
  width: auto;
  border: 0px solid;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin:0">
  <table id="wrapTable">
    <tr>
      <th> Col1 </th>
      <th> Col2 </th>
      <th> Col3 </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Row1 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Row2 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Row3 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Row4 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Row5 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Row6 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Row7 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Row8 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Row9 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Row10 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table id="wrapTable">
    <tr>
      <th> Col1 </th>
      <th> Col2 </th>
      <th> Col3 </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Row11 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Row12 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Row13 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Row14 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Row15 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Row16 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Row17 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Row18 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Row19 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Row20 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```